# Match trailing <br> tag with Regex

Tags: regex

I have a long single line string of HTML. I am trying to use regex to match the `<br>` tag after the line that begins with `START`. The last word in the line will vary.

HTML:

```
<br>This is the first sentence<br>START capture tag<br>This is the third sentance<br>
```

I was able to use this expression to capture the sentence:

```
START.*?(?=<)
```

I can't figure out how to select the trailing br tag without including the sentence before it. I tried using a positive lookbehind but it won't accept quantifiers.

https://regex101.com/r/lM3eH7/1

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: What is the expected output for the above input HTML string?

Comment: Just '<br>'. I will be using stringByReplacingMatchesInString in Swift to run a find a replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

By using `\K` we can reset the capture to only match the desired text.

```
START.*?\K<br>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**Live Demo**: https://regex101.com/r/fM0bG0/1

More information on the `\K` can be had at [regular-expressions.info/keep.html](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html)

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you. Don't know how I missed that option in my hours of reading.